# What is the current state of SSD support in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ssd

I will be receiving a new laptop with an Intel 520 solid-state drive. I use Windows to meet the requirements of the few applications and games. Otherwise, I prefer UNIX-like environment, particularly Ubuntu Linux. Ideally, I would dual-boot the system for bare metal performance. is Ubuntu optimized out-of-the-box for modern SSDx yet? Or, am I better off (from the standpoint of performance and reliability) relegating Ubuntu to virtual machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu by default uses ext4, which has quite a few performance optimizations for SSDs.  It also supports TRIM out of the box, although [it has to be enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18903/how-to-enable-trim).  I dualboot between Windows 7 and Xubuntu 12.04 on a laptop with a 256GB SSD (128GB for each OS) and the Linux performance is quite good:

```
fluffy@inkpad:~$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/bigfile bs=1M count=1024
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 3.21788 s, 334 MB/s
fluffy@inkpad:~$ dd of=/dev/null if=/tmp/bigfile bs=1M count=1024
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 0.249378 s, 4.3 GB/s
```

Comment: You have to explicitly enable trim on ext4 with a mount option

Comment: Which you really shouldn't need to do.

Comment: @psusi Thanks, I didn't realize that.  I'll add a link to an appropriate 'ask ubuntu' thread I just found.

Comment: @SeanW. But it doesn't hurt, right?

Comment: @fluffy No, but I would have thought that TRIM would be enabled by default in drives that support it considering Ubuntu is meant to be a user friendly distro.

Comment: @SeanW., the upstream kernel guys still consider it to be dangerous and untested, so it's off by default.